# Is my definition of vector space correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A set containing the linear combination of basis vectors is called a vector space. Is my definition and understanding of vector space correct? If not, what exactly is a vector space?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As understanding it's basically correct, however, as definition it's not rigorous enough.

Comment: So you're taking the terms "linear combination" and "basis" for granted, but is it possible to define and understand those concepts without first knowing what a vector space is?

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments or on the answer that has been posted?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is nonresponsive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these amazing answers.

Comment: That's not really engaging with comments or answers. In particular, if you have found Paul's answer helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real vector space is a set $V$ along with binary operation $+: V \times V \to V$ called "addition" and a binary operation $\cdot : \Bbb R \times V \to V$, called "scalar multiplication", which satisfy the following conditions:

- commutivity of addition: for all $u,v \in V, u+v = v+u$
- associativity of addition: for all $u, v, w \in V, (u + v) + w = u + (v + w)$
- additive identity: There is an element $0 \in V$ such that for all $v \in V, 0 + v = v$.
- additive inverse: for every $v \in V$, there is a $w \in v$ such that $v + w = 0$. $w$ is commonly denoted as $-v$ and "$u - v$" means $u + (-v)$.
- associativity of scalar multiplication: for every $r, s \in \Bbb R, v \in V, (rs)v = r(sv)$.
- multiplicative identity: for all $v \in V, 1v = v$.
- distributivity: for all $r \in \Bbb R, u,v \in V, r(u+v) = ru + rv$.

That is it. A more general definition swaps out $\Bbb R$ will some generic field $\Bbb F$, but that is all there is to being a vector space.

A very generic way of generating real vector spaces is to take some set $A$, and consider the set $V$ of all functions $f : A \to \Bbb R$. The addition is just point-wise addition of the two functions: for all $x \in A$,
$$(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
And scalar multiplication is just multiplying the functions by constant values: for all $x \in A$, $$(rf)(x) = r \cdot [f(x)]
$$
These meet all the conditions specified above, making $V$ a vector space. And pretty much *every* real vector space you will ever encounter is a subspace of some function space exactly like this. Even $\Bbb R^n$ is the just the set of all functions from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \Bbb R$.